# 2 Macs and a Dell, not seeing the internet the same

Tags: macos, networking, podcasts

My house has a 2006 Macbook Pro with Snow Leopard, a 2005 Macbook with Leopard and a 2010 Dell laptop with Windows 7.

My wife uses the Macs as her computers, she loves listening to This American Life from NPR.
Both of the Macs often have trouble getting the podcasts via iTunes so I looked into it.

As I sit here with all 3 laptops...both Macs cannot see the latest podcast (#438) but the Dell can. If I go to the This American Life and navigate to [listen to it online](http://podcast.thisamericanlife.org/podcast/438.mp3) the Dell gets there and plays it, but neither Mac does. If I go through iTunes, no dice.  If I navigate to the site, no dice.

They are all 3 on the same network running through a Time Capsule today, but was actually running through a Linksys the previous year and has been run through a NetGear.

All 3 of those routers had the exact same problem.  The Dell has never had the problem and the Macs don't ALWAYS have the problem.  Oddly enough my wife has the This American Life app on her iPhone...and occasionally it too cannot see the latest podcast.

Anyone have any idea where to look to fix this?  I am pretty qualified when it comes to computers whether they be Mac or Windows....but this is driving me nuts!

Comment: Do all of these machines have static addresses or are they on dhcp?

Comment: Yes, check DHCP like Mike G suggested, but also DNS. Try replacing the Mac DNS settings with OpenDNS or Google DNS. I've found my Mac far more responsive with Google's DNS.

Comment: The IPs for Google's DNS are 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4.